# decodeURI doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, json, decode, encode

I have a string, something like

`"Bob\u0027s Burgers"`

`decodeURI` doesn't seem to be turning that `\u0027` into an apostrophe like it seems like it ought to. To the point, it just leaves it alone. `encodeURI` seems to do all kinds of stuff to it but `decodeURI` doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Am I missing something here? Or as they say in less eloquent English, "what do?"

Edit: code that is returning the string:
`courseNames` holds the value that is needed

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/urlforaction",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {eventID: model.EventID},
        complete: function (data) {
            courseNames = data["responseText"].substring(1).substring(0, data["responseText"].length-2).split(',');
            //courseNames = courseNames.split(',');
            //courseNames = courseNames.replace('"', '');
            for (i = 0; i < courseNames.length; i++) {
                courseNameHTMLStream += courseNames[i] + '<br/>';
            }
        }
    });
```

Double Edit: The responseText contains a string like this:

"Category Title,Bob/u0027s Burger 1,Bob/u0027s Burger 2"

Comment: That's not how special characters are supposed to be encoded for URIs. Check what `encodeURI("Bob's Burgers")` returns.

Comment: Yeah, among other things, it turns spaces in %20 for urls.

Comment: Actually, i was wrong.. `unescape` is deprecated.. sorry. use `decodeURIComponent` instead

Comment: It still didn't work. Deprecated or not wouldn't have made too much of an issue.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tested it on Chrome, ff, safari, opera - (dont have IE though) and seemed to work for me.

Comment: It's failing in firefox and chrome but it needs to work in all browsers

Comment: How exactly do you have that data “as a string”? If this was a line of JS code, then you would not even notice that “special notation” (which is a way of writing unicode characters in JS btw.), because it would be eliminated (“translated”) by the parser already. So do you have that as a value inside a variable, including the quotation marks in the value? Since this would be a valid JS expression (if it includes the quotation marks(, you could `eval` it – but then you better be damn sure it doesn’t contain any actual JS commands or such … so, please clarify.

Comment: There is a possibility that your JSON is invalid. Are you doing a `JSON.parse(...)` and then decoding this string ?

Comment: It's a json encoded string that returns from an ajax c# function. It's being split and thrown into a variable. Not the best way to do it but I don't have a lot of choice in the matter atm

Comment: That syntax is a *native JavaScript Unicode escape sequence*. It's odd that you're ending up with that string at all. What *exactly* does the JSON look like?  It would have to have two `\` characters before the "u" in order for your JavaScript code to end up with that string.

Comment: And now … what does `data["responseText"]` contain?

Comment: Edited question to answer your question

Comment: Data["responseText"] contains string similar to the following: "Category Title,Bob/u0027s Burger 1,Bob/u0027s Burger 2"

Comment: Including the quotation marks?

Comment: And if you are interested in the single values, then why does your C# program not return them as an _array_ inside the JSON in the first place?

Comment: I'm getting that directly from a console.debug statement so yes, the quotes are in there. By the time it gets to the loop, the quotes have been stripped out.

Comment: The c# is reutrning return Json(string.Join(",", <a complicated EF join statement>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68241/discussion-between-metalphoenix-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just passing that through `JSON.parse` should solve the issue,

```
var foo = '"Category Title,Bob\\u0027s Burger 1,Bob\\u0027s Burger 2"';

console.log(foo);
// outputs "Category Title,Bob\u0027s Burger 1,Bob\u0027s Burger 2"
console.log(JSON.parse(foo));
// outputs Category Title,Bob's Burger 1,Bob's Burger 2
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tj38pehv/1/

From there on, you can continue splitting it at the comma.

---

From comments:

> The c# is reutrning `return Json(string.Join(",", <a complicated EF join statement>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Well why are you joining those values there in the first place? If `<a complicated EF join statement>` results in an array-like structure, then just encoding *that* as JSON, instead of making a comma-separated string of it, should give you an *array* of single values in your JavaScript straight away …

Comment: That was it. Whoever the dingbat was that did that in the first place (me, maybe? it's inherited code so I'll go ahead and take ownership of that screw-up on general principle) didn't take the time to deal with it in a JSON way and for whatever reason I just wasn't seeing it. I owe you one at some point, not sure I could return that favor though. THanks.

Comment: No worries, we all know it can be hard sometimes to see one’s own “stupid” mistakes when one has been working on a piece of code too long, and how it can take a fresh set of eyes to point out said stupidity ;-)